# howto get exit code of script running within expect

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

for some time I am struggling to get the exit code of a script which I am running from within expect.
It is a BASH script and the questionable part looks like this:

```
  expect -c "
    log_file $LOG
    spawn su - $ora_user
    expect ""
    send \"source $oraenv_binary\r\"
    expect \"ORACLE_SID = \[$ora_user\] \?\"
    send \"$SID\r\"
    expect \"The Oracle base has been set to /oracle/$SID\"
    send \"$execPATHroot/$subscript $args_subscript\r\"
    expect ""
    send \"echo \$?\r\"
    expect -re \"(\\d+)\" {
    set result \$expect_out(1,string)
    }
    send_user \"subscript exit code: \$result\"
    log_file
    send \"exit\r\"
    expect ""
    exit [lindex \$result 3]"
    sub_rc=$?
```

Needed to say that this is one of many tries to get the code, however, unsuccessfully. I guess that my problem lies in incorrectly escaped characters or wrong use of brackets.....

When debugging, I am getting the following:

```
[336] oraenv_binary=/usr/local/bin/oraenv
[338] expect -c '
    log_file /var/opt/osit/oracle/log/ora_sbp_patching_root.bash.log
    spawn su - oracle
    expect
    send "source /usr/local/bin/oraenv\r"
    expect "ORACLE_SID = \[oracle\] \?"
    send "H95\r"
    expect "The Oracle base has been set to /oracle/H95"
    send "/opt/osit/oracle/bin/ora_sbp_patching_orausr.bash -s H95 -a CHECK -p /imports/e2r2s48ifde0002/CDSAP/DB/oracle/ORA19/SBP/SBP_1915_220419_202205 -h /imports/e2r2s48ifde0002/CDSAP/DB/oracle/ORA19/SBP/SBP_1915_220419_202205/README19P_2205-70004508.HTM -u oracle\r"
    expect
    send "echo $?\r"
    expect -re "(\d+)" {
    set result $expect_out(1,string)
    }
    send_user "subscript exit code: $result"
    log_file
    send "exit\r"
    expect
    exit [lindex $result 3]'
```

.....subscript runs here OK with exit code 0 in this case

```
-sh-4.2$ subscript exit code: decho $?
0
-sh-4.2$ exit
logout
expected integer but got ""
    while executing
"exit [lindex $result 3]"
[357] sub_rc=0
```

It seems to me that the regex part "(\d+)" is not OK, but perhaps, it is completely a mess... :-)
Please help.

I have read and tried these recommendations:
[Is there a way to expect output without removing it from the buffer in Tcl expect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076016/is-there-a-way-to-expect-output-without-removing-it-from-the-buffer-in-tcl-expec)

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/How+Expect+can+capture+the+exit+code+from+a+remote+command

https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/144812-expect-script-obtain-exit-code-remote-command.html

Comment: is `\d+` valid regex in `expect`? If you suspect that's the issue you could try replacing it with `[0-9]+`

Comment: @I0_ol  thanks for comment. honestly I am not sure if TCL uses the same regex stuff as BASH for example...Anyway, I have tried it, but it did not worked. Neither with [0-9]+ , nor with \[0-9\]+

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure as I've never really used `expect`. What is the code `exit [lindex \$result 3]` supposed to be doing?

Comment: here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850287/expect-how-to-get-the-exit-code-from-spawned-process/46852275#46852275

Comment: `\d+` is a valid RE in Expect and Tcl.

Comment: @DonalFellows you're right, I have just found it here https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl20a.html

Comment: Why are you executing as string? If you create a file.bash with that content, $? will work!

Comment: sorry I do not understand. What do I execute as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final code which works is as follows (much of the credit goes to Glenn for his numerous advices) :

```
expect -c "
log_file $LOG
spawn su - $ora_user
expect -re {\$ $}
send \"PS1='>'\r\"
expect -re {>$}
send \"source $oraenv_binary\r\"
expect {ORACLE_SID = \[$ora_user\] ? }
send \"$SID\r\"
expect \"The Oracle base has been set to /oracle/$SID\"
send \"$execPATHroot/$subscript $args_subscript\r\"
expect { (subscript) ; exp_continue }
expect -re {>$}
send \"echo \$?\r\"
expect -re {(\d+)\r\n>$} {set result \$expect_out(1,string)}
send_user \"subscript exit code:\$result\n\"
log_file
send \"exit\r\"
expect \"logout\"
exit [lindex \$result 0]"
sub_rc=$?
echo sub_rc:$sub_rc
```

The first thing after `spawn su - $ora_user` is to set the prompt by `send \"PS1='>'\r\"` in order to make new lines with prompt less intrusive to expect.

Then after `send \"$execPATHroot/$subscript $args_subscript\r\"` I have used the fact, that I have written the subscript to have every line of output populated by `(subscript)` keyword. So while the subscript produces the output, the expect keeps going by `exp_continue`.

When the `$subscript` ends, the prompt `>` appears into which the expect sends `echo $?` to get exit code of the `$subscript`.
This appears on the screen as:

```
>echo $?
0
>
```

so the code should expect the integer, return and the new line with prompt - i.e. `{(\d+)\r\n>$}`. At that time the expect matches the output and `expect_out(1,string)` is correctly populated:

```
send: sending "echo $?\r" to { exp7 }
Gate keeper glob pattern for '(\d+)\r\n>$' is '*
>'. Activating booster.
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression "(\d+)\r\n>$"? Gate "*\r\n>"? gate=no
echo $?
0
>
expect: does "echo $?\r\n0\r\n>" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression "(\d+)\r\n>$"? Gate "*\r\n>"? gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "0\r\n>"
expect: set expect_out(1,string) "0"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "echo $?\r\n0\r\n>"
```

Another thing to mention is `\n` within `send_user \"subscript exit code:\$result\n\"` so to have new line next..

The last change to the code in question is:

```
exit [lindex \$result 0]"
```

I have changed the index to `0` as variable result has just one item and index `0` stands for 1st item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
    expect -re "(\d+)" {
    set result $expect_out(1,string)
    }
    send_user "subscript exit code: $result"
```

and we can see the output is

```
-sh-4.2$ subscript exit code: decho $?
0
```

Because the regular expression `"(\d+)"` is in *double quotes*, backslash substitutions will occur, and the pattern becomes `(d+)` which may not match (do you get a 10 second delay at that point?) -- I suspect this is why `$result` is empty.

Backslashes are prevalent in regular expressions. Using braces to quote them is the way to go:

```
expect -re {\d+} {set result $expect_out(0,string)}
```

---

Running your expect code with `expect -d` (or set `exp_internal 1` in the code) emits very verbose expect debug output that is extremely useful to see how your patterns are matching (or not).

---

Using quoted shell heredocs is (IMO) preferable to using quoted strings to encapsulate code.

Consider

```bash
expect -c "
send_user \"my home is \$env(HOME)\\n\"
"
```

versus

```bash
expect << 'END_CODE'
    send_user "my home is $env(HOME)\n"
END_CODE
```

With this technique, you pass shell variable to expect through the environment:

```bash
export ora_user=oracle

expect << 'END_EXPECT'
    #...
    spawn su - $env(ora_user)
END_EXPECT
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and points mentioned.
Regarding the braces versus double quotes - I have changed it like that, but no effect. I have those double quotes escaped by backslash within my code - I think the effect is the same, however, definitely it looks nicer to me and evidently it is safer.

Comment: Within the double quoted code block, you'll need to do `expect -re \"(\\\\d+)\"`

Comment: Thanks! The 10 seconds delay ceased, and the whole run is much swifter, however I am still not getting what I want. I have searched for similar stuff here and elsewhere, and expecting of the prompt is mentioned very often. So I have put  `expect \"\\\\$ \"` so to expect the prompt and empty space after subscript run. It is nicer, but not OK still.
`-sh-4.2$ echo $?
0
-sh-4.2$ exit
logout
expected integer but got ""
    while executing
"exit [lindex $result 3]"`

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your answer Glenn, interesting points mentioned.
Regarding the braces versus double quotes - I have changed it like that, but no effect. I have those double quotes escaped by backslash within my code - I think the effect is the same, however, definitely it looks nicer to me and evidently it is safer.
I have played with the debug mode of expect - thanks for that, I can see much more info.
I have noticed that expect holds much more stuff than I "expected" :-)

==> this is just a snippet:

```
.\r\n-sh-4.2$ " (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression "\d+"? (No Gate, RE only) gate=yes re=yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "4"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n-sh-4"
can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such element in array
    while executing
"set result $expect_out(1,string)"
    invoked from within
"expect -re {\d+} {set result $expect_out(1,string)}"
```

As you can see, when I am sending the subscript to be executed I am expecting "" i.e. nothing, just the new prompt line.
However, at that point expect is full of stuff, not at all blank - I think, I need to define the prompt exactly:

```
-sh-4.2$
```

and then I need to expect it, together with echoed exit code $? and somehow separate exit code integer to get what I want...... I will keep trying.

Comment: Yes, `expect -re {\d+}` is matching the "4" in the prompt. `spawn su ...` then `expect -re {\$ $}` to match the prompt, then `send "PS1='>'\r"` to make the prompt less intrusive: `expect -re {>$}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @glennjackman, thanks a lot. This setting up PS1 removed some confusion from the expect.....so I am getting closer to the wanted result :-)
While debugging,...it seems like expecting new prompt `expect -re {>$}` after subscript ends, is not working.

Comment: @glennjackman, It seems like the expect is not waiting for the subscript to finish with prompt. The expect tries to match `{\d}` right after send the subscript to be executed, which results to match first number it finds within subscript parameters, unfortunately.

Comment: well, it AMOST works now, also I think my current solution is quite rude: 
my subscript run has the string `(subscript)` in every line. So in order to sort of wait for the subscript to finish, I have put  right after `send \"$execPATHroot/$subscript $args_subscript\r\"` one extra line: `expect { (subscript) ; exp_continue }` with the aim to recognize every such a line as "unimportant" so to not filling `expect_out` with confusing stuff. The rest is still little bit confused: `>echo $?
0
>subscript exit code: 0exit`

Comment: You could match the digits followed by crnl followed by the prompt: that would limit the digits that get matched: `expect -re {(\d+)\r\n\S+\$ $}` -- expect uses `\r\n` for all newlines.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I have changed it little bit to match `send "PS1='>'\r"` as you have advised me earlier, so: `expect -re {(\d+)\r\n>$} {set result \$expect_out(1,string)}`. Now the expect matches the output nicely: `expect: does "echo $?\r\n0\r\n>" (spawn_id exp7) match regular expression "(\d+)\r\n>$"? Gate "*\r\n>"? gate=yes re=yes` while populating expect_out with exit code `expect: set expect_out(1,string) "0"`, that's great. However, the variable result is not populated, I am investigating why....

Comment: so, the variable `result` is really being populated correctly: `subscript exit code:0`, however when exiting expect with `exit [lindex $result 3]`, the following complain appears: `expected integer but got "" while executing "exit [lindex $result 3]"`. The variable result is defined by: `{set result \$expect_out(1,string)}`, but the expect is then sending other commands and it seems to me, that by changing  `expect_out(1,string)` on the way, the variable results in change too - I cannot think otherwise....so I need somehow to keep the variable value till exit.

Comment: well this TCL is funny :) I have done rtfm by reading [https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exit] and [https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/lindex] and I have realized that the number 3 in `exit [lindex \$result 3]` is wrong as it is an index in the list. The list of variable `result` consist of just one item, so I need to take index 0 - i.e. the 1st item: `exit [lindex \$result 0]` .... I will write my answer to my question with the explanation why I did what.